# No exact match was found - Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, peoplepicker

```
   whenever we give wrong account in people picker we will get
```

"No exact match was found" error message. In Internet Explorer it is

showing only "No exact match was found" but in firefox it is showing

"No exact match was found for \" i want to

hide the account name. I Need only the "No exact match was found" error message. How can i hide it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between the browsers because in IE functionality is offered to correct the name (like in Word, click the name underlined with a red wiggly line). Functionality which isn't in FF or Chrome.

But to hide the error message displayed in SharePoint is hard, at least it requires editing standard SharePoint controls. I think you have to change the PeoplePicker-control or the page it is on. These files can be found in the [12]-hive.

But editing those files is at your own risk! You might end up with broken SharePoint.